# elasticsearch java response stuck

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I use spring data elasticsearch to query and save doc into elasticsearch(7.12):

- spring boot: 2.7.1
- spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch: 2.7.1
- spring-data-elasticsearch: 4.4.1

after running a while, all the worker threads stuck when invoking `CrudRepository#save` method to save doc. Here is one thread dump:

```
status: org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture@11ab10df WAITING


java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.get(BasicFuture.java:82)
org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:70)
org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:295)
org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:287)
org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2699)
org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2171)
org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2137)
org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2105)
org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.refresh(IndicesClient.java:900)
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RestIndexTemplate.lambda$doRefresh$8(RestIndexTemplate.java:178)
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RestIndexTemplate$$Lambda$1112/1741758039.doWithClient(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:582)
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RestIndexTemplate.doRefresh(RestIndexTemplate.java:178)
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractIndexTemplate.refresh(AbstractIndexTemplate.java:163)
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.doRefresh(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:313)
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.executeAndRefresh(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:361)
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.save(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:188)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker$$Lambda$1061/168251875.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.save(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor60.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.save(Unknown Source)
...
```

Seems that it stuck on this code line(RestClient.java:295) to wait for es response but never got it, so `Future#get()` is wait forever:

```
        try {
            httpResponse = client.execute(context.requestProducer, context.asyncResponseConsumer, context.context, null).get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
```

**What i wanna know is why it doesn't throw something like `TimeoutException` rather than wait the response forever?**

Plus, timeout is set to 30s and keep alive is enabled by default, and all these info
can be found in the below debug log:

```
2022-08-02 17:43:28.652 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl 154 - http-outgoing-0 10.234.8.18:39418<->103.74.51.222:443[ACTIVE][rw:][ACTIVE][rw][NEED_UNWRAP][0][0][311]: Set timeout 30000
2022-08-02 17:43:28.652 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers 134 - http-outgoing-0 >> GET / HTTP/1.1
2022-08-02 17:43:28.652 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers 137 - http-outgoing-0 >> X-Elastic-Client-Meta: es=7.17.4p,jv=1.8,t=7.17.4p,hc=4.1.5
2022-08-02 17:43:28.652 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers 137 - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Length: 0
2022-08-02 17:43:28.652 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers 137 - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: elasticsearch-xxx.com:443
2022-08-02 17:43:28.652 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers 137 - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2022-08-02 17:43:28.652 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers 137 - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: elasticsearch-java/7.17.4-SNAPSHOT (Java/1.8.0_292)
2022-08-02 17:43:28.652 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers 137 - http-outgoing-0 >> Authorization: Basic secret
2022-08-02 17:43:28.653 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl 108 - http-outgoing-0 10.234.8.18:39418<->103.74.51.222:443[ACTIVE][rw:][ACTIVE][rw][NEED_UNWRAP][0][0][311]: Event set [w]
2022-08-02 17:43:28.654 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec 273 - [exchange: 1] Request completed
2022-08-02 17:43:28.726 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl 222 - http-outgoing-0 10.234.8.18:39418<->103.74.51.222:443[ACTIVE][rw:w][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][334]: 305 bytes written
2022-08-02 17:43:28.726 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 >> "GET / HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.726 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 >> "X-Elastic-Client-Meta: es=7.17.4p,jv=1.8,t=7.17.4p,hc=4.1.5[\r][\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.727 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.727 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: elasticsearch-xxx.com:443[\r][\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.727 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.727 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: elasticsearch-java/7.17.4-SNAPSHOT (Java/1.8.0_292)[\r][\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.727 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Authorization: Basic secret[\r][\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.727 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.727 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch 71 - http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE] Request ready
2022-08-02 17:43:28.727 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl 116 - http-outgoing-0 10.234.8.18:39418<->103.74.51.222:443[ACTIVE][r:w][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0]: Event cleared [w]
2022-08-02 17:43:28.732 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl 206 - http-outgoing-0 10.234.8.18:39418<->103.74.51.222:443[ACTIVE][r:r][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0]: 698 bytes read
2022-08-02 17:43:28.732 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.732 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "Server: YDWS[\r][\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.732 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Tue, 02 Aug 2022 09:43:28 GMT[\r][\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.732 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.732 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Length: 536[\r][\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.732 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.732 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.732 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "{[\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.732 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "  "name" : "es-ad-es-node-2",[\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.733 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "  "cluster_name" : "es-ad",[\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.733 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "  "cluster_uuid" : "z6oA-NW_ShmpJJQSXeyOIQ",[\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.733 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "  "version" : {[\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.733 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "    "number" : "7.11.2",[\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.733 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "    "build_flavor" : "default",[\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.733 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "    "build_type" : "docker",[\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.733 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "    "build_hash" : "3e5a16cfec50876d20ea77b075070932c6464c7d",[\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.733 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "    "build_date" : "2021-03-06T05:54:38.141101Z",[\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.733 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "    "build_snapshot" : false,[\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.734 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "    "lucene_version" : "8.7.0",[\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.734 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",[\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.734 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"[\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.734 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "  },[\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.734 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"[\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.734 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire 54 - http-outgoing-0 << "}[\n]"
2022-08-02 17:43:28.736 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers 123 - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2022-08-02 17:43:28.736 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers 126 - http-outgoing-0 << Server: YDWS
2022-08-02 17:43:28.736 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers 126 - http-outgoing-0 << Date: Tue, 02 Aug 2022 09:43:28 GMT
2022-08-02 17:43:28.736 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers 126 - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
2022-08-02 17:43:28.736 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers 126 - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Length: 536
2022-08-02 17:43:28.736 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers 126 - http-outgoing-0 << Connection: keep-alive
2022-08-02 17:43:28.736 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch 106 - http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE(536)] Response received
2022-08-02 17:43:28.737 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec 286 - [exchange: 1] Response received HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2022-08-02 17:43:28.739 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch 81 - http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE(536)] Input ready
2022-08-02 17:43:28.740 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec 325 - [exchange: 1] Consume content
2022-08-02 17:43:28.741 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient 300 - [exchange: 1] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
2022-08-02 17:43:28.741 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec 385 - [exchange: 1] Response processed
2022-08-02 17:43:28.741 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient 241 - [exchange: 1] releasing connection
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Plus: not only save requests stuck here, search requests(eg: `findById` in spring data es) also stuck at the same line.

Comment: It seems that the save is doing a refresh after every insert, which will slow down the application/the cluster when doing lot of document inserts. How do you configure Spring Data Elasticsearch? Since 4.4 the default refresh should be to not d a refresh (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch-migration-guide-4.3-4.4.breaking-changes)?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch i'v discovered there is not only save, but also search request(`findById`), all stuck in the same place - waiting for the response. And from the es debug log, it seems there is no immediate refresh in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem finally... spring data elasticsearch(and java elasticsearch client itself) by default does not enable keepalive support on connection between the client and elasticsearch.

This only happens on high concurrency conditions!

Here are similar links:

- https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/65213
- https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/65909

and spring data doesn't have support for config keepalive in properties, so code config must be involved:

```
    @Bean
    public RestClientBuilderCustomizer keepalive() {
        return new RestClientBuilderCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(RestClientBuilder builder) {

            }

            @Override
            public void customize(HttpAsyncClientBuilder builder) {
                // enable keep alive
                builder.setDefaultIOReactorConfig(IOReactorConfig.custom().setSoKeepAlive(true).build());
            }
        };
    }
```

I do think spring data or elasticsearch should enable keepalive by default!

Comment: The unresponsiveness probably does not come from Spring Data Elasticsearch, but from the cluster refreshing. As for the configuration: Spring Data Elasticsearch does not use **any** properties for configuration, this is a Spring Boot thing.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch this is a config for java es client http client, to enable keep alive by default. so it's actually a config about es client.

Comment: I know, I implemented that. I was referring to your sentence "spring data doesn't have support for config keepalive in properties"

Comment: @P.J.Meisch okok, i misunderstood the sentence. nice job man :thumbup

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Thanks for your job, spring data elasticsearch really lightens my life. And is there any plan spring data elasticsearch includes keepalive as a default setting or makes it configurable in the properties? I do think it's important enough to do that.

Comment: We do not the change the default behaviour of the Elasticsearch client components, we offer possibilities to adjust these. As for having properties for that: that's a Spring Boot question, not for Spring Data Elasticsearch.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch ok, i'll try to request spring boot to find help. Thanks~